# Units in finite rings

Tags: co.combinatorics, ra.rings-and-algebras

Going trough the list of finite rings (with unit) until order 17, I noticed the following was true:

-There is a unique finite ring of a given order which has the maximal number of units.(which might generalise the famous statement that there is a unique finite field of a given prime power order)

-The sequence which gives the maximal number of units of a ring with n elements is as follows from n=2 to n=17:
https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C2%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C4%2C10%2C6%2C12%2C6%2C8%2C15%2C16&sort=&language=english&go=Search

So the maximum might be attained at direct product of the corresponding fields which might explain the sequence?

So in a short conjecture one might guess the following (without evidence):

```
       There is a unique finite ring of order $n=p_1^{e_1} ... p_r^{e_r} $
       such that the size of the    
       unit group of R is maximal and $R$ is isomorphic to the product of 
       finite fields of the corresponding size such that the unit group of 
        R has order $(p_1^{e_1}-1) ... (p_r^{e_r}-1)$
```

Comment: Every finite ring is the direct product of its "Sylow subrings." From here the argument is straightforward.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan havent heard of such a thing. feel free to post an answer or a reference.

Comment: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Finite_ring_is_internal_direct_product_of_its_Sylow_subrings found that. now its clear. thanks for the comment.

Comment: By "unit" you mean "invertible" (except in "ring with unit"). From the tags I expect you mean associative unital rings (not necessarily commutative).

Comment: @YCor yes, you are correct.

Comment: The conjecture seems to be true and quite immediate: the case when the order is a prime power is straightforward (maximum is achieved by the field of the given size). The general case follows by decomposing as the direct product of its "Sylow" subrings.

Comment: Yes, thats what I figured out after Qiaochu Yuan gave me the hint with the Sylow subrings.